# Invocation sequence of constructors and destructors?

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

Suppose we have two objects with automatic storage duration:

```
{
   ClassA objA(...);
   ClassB objB(...);

   // [A] code that uses objA and objB.

   // [B] objA is no longer used after this point.

   // ... more code ...

}  // [C] objA and objB go out of scope.
```

1. Does the C++ standard specify the relative sequencing of the constructors for `objA` and `objB`?  For example, can we assume that any side-effects caused by `objA`'s constructor will be visible when `objB`'s constructor is invoked?
2. At [C] destructors for `objA` and `objB` will be invoked.   Is there a similar sequencing requirement on these destructors?
3. Finally, if liveness analysis shows that `objA` is dead after point [B], is a C++ compiler allowed to invoke the destructor for `objA` "early", i.e., between points [B] and [C] in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1 Does the C++ standard specify the relative sequencing of the constructors for objA and objB? For example, can we assume that any side-effects caused by objA's constructor will be visible when objB's constructor is invoked?

Yes. `objA` is constructed before `objB`.

> 2 At [C] destructors for objA and objB will be invoked. Is there a similar sequencing requirement on these destructors?

Yes, `objB` is destroyed before `objA`. The order of destruction is the reverse of the order of construction.

> 3 Finally, if liveness analysis shows that objA is dead after point [B], is a C++ compiler allowed to invoke the destructor for objA "early", i.e., between points [B] and [C] in the code?

Not if there are side effects. The compiler must follow the *as-if* rule.

To clarify: the as-if rule applies to all of the the three points above.

Answer (score 2):

§6.6.2

> On exit from a scope (however accomplished), objects with automatic storage duration (3.7.3) that have been constructed in that scope are destroyed in the **reverse order** of their construction.

Pretty much answers all of your three questions from this reference.